# How to retrieve documents with createdAt more than 48 hours in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to retrieve documents where the createdAt timestamp is more than 48 hours in mongoose.

Here's my sample code below but it doesn't retrieve any documents even though there're documents that match the condition.

```
Model.find({
    createdAt: { $lt: new Date(Date.now() - 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) },
});
```

NB: The createdAt field is the default in mongoose when timestamp is enabled `{ timestamps: true }`

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help out, thanks in advance.

Comment: You're finding the documents created more than 48h. To get the documents created within 48h, use `$gt` instead.

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc sorry, it was a typo. I want to retrieve records with createdAt more than 48hours

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB aggegation framework, we have access [$$NOW](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.NOW) (Standalone) | [$$CLUSTER_TIME](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.CLUSTER_TIME) (Cluster) variable which returns current date.

If we subtract `172800000` miliseconds (48 hours) from current date and use `$expr` operator, we can get desired result.

Try this one:

```
Model.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gte: [
          "$createdAt",
          {
            $toDate: {
              $subtract: [
                {
                  $toLong: "$$CLUSTER_TIME"
                },
                172800000 // 2 x 24 x 60 x 60 x 1000
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]).exec();
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RjbxTtiSMmW)

Comment: I got this `MongoError: Use of undefined variable: NOW`

Comment: @Lawrence What is your MongoDB version? I suppose you have 4.2

Comment: Am sure its the latest cos am using the cloud version at https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas

Comment: From mongoose docs: By default, Mongoose uses the current time new Date() to get the current time https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps

Comment: @Lawrence. You need to use `$$CLUSTER_TIME` (because atlas is cluster) instead of `$$NOW` (standalone)

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to help out.

Comment: You can only use $$NOW and $$CLUSTER_TIME with MongoDB 4.2 version or newer

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var days= 2;
var date = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() - days));

Model.find({createdAt : {$lt : date}}).count());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that tried to help out.

My solution above works, I wasn't getting any records at that time cos unknowing to me my env file was pointing to another MongoDB server.